# Keycode event for BACKSPACE in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, gluon

I am doing a project in JavaFX, using Java 8 and [Gluon scenebuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). I want to detect when `backspace` is pressed inside a `TextField`. This is the code I am using:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent kEvent) {
    if (kEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        System.out.println("Backspace pressed");
    }
```

This code is inside the controller file, called `FXMLDocumentController`, which controls the GUI xml file `FXMLDocument`. You can see from the image below the function is called whenever a key is typed inside `TextField`. This works with all the letters/numbers, but not with `backspace`.

[image: Gluon scene builder settings]

Theoretically it should work, but it doesn't.

How can I manage typing of the `backspace` button?

Edit:

Notice that putting this exact function on the root of the elements, on the "Window itself" (which is the `AnchorPane`) works. The problem is with reading the pressing of the `backspace` inside the `TextField`. You can see in the image below where I've put the function:

[image: On the window backspace's detecting works]

Comment: Does changing `KeyCode.BACK_SPACE` to `KeyCode.VK_BACK_SPACE` work?

Comment: I think VK_BACK_SPACE exists only on AWT, because the compiler says it can't find the symbol:
`error: cannot find symbol.  symbol: variable VK_BACK_SPACE, location: class KeyCode`

Comment: Can you log the value of the keycode and report back. Add `System.out.println(kEvent.getCode());`

Comment: @F.Alessandro The keyCode returns undefined when its a keyTyped event. I think a solution would be to use the getCharacter() method to get the unicode represecntation of backspace and then compare it to U+0008 which is the unicode for backspace

Comment: `System.out.println(kEvent.getCode());` returns exactly "BACK_SPACE".

Comment: if it returns that even when pressed inside the text field, so just change the if statement to `if(kEvent.getCode().toString.equals("BACK_SPACE"))`

Comment: Just checked again, both `System.out.println(kEvent.getCode());` and `System.out.println(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE);` return "BACK_SPACE" in the log.

Comment: Unfortunately the statement if `(kEvent.getCode().toString().equals("BACK_SPACE")) {...}` doesn't work inside the `TextField`, but works if the functions are on the root element of the GUI (as explained in the original post, under the "Edit" part).

Comment: @F.Alessandro did you try the method that i wrote above with using the getCharacter() method?

Comment: The statement `if (kEvent.getCode().toString().equals("\u0008")) {...}` doesn't work. I always get problems with UTF-8, is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use your `keyPressed` method in either `on key pressed` or `on key released`.

In the [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html), it states that:

> No key typed events are generated for keys that don't generate Unicode
>   characters (e.g., action keys, modifier keys, etc.).

<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is consider an `Action Key`.

Answer (score 3):

In the screenshot of your SceneBuilder I can see you are referencing the `keyPressed(KeyEvent kEvent)` controller method with *On Key **Typed*** not *On Key **Pressed***.

For events of `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED` the value of `getCode()` is always `KeyCode.UNDEFINED`.

---

**Edit:** I came back to this answer and reread your question. I want to clarify something but what I said above is still correct.

In your edit you mention the "exact" same setup works with the `AnchorPane` but when looking at your screenshot there are some differences. For your `AnchorPane` you have the controller method referenced for *all three types*: On Key Pressed, On Key Released, and On Key Typed.

This means that the method should be called up to 3 times for each key stroke (when the events reach the `AnchorPane`). Once when pressed, once for typed (if the key is capable of sending typed events - see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49575995/6395627) by Sedrick for clarification), and then once for released. Because of this, the method *will* work for the *pressed* and *released* events, but it *won't* work for the *typed* events.

In other words, the reason your code works for the `AnchorPane` but not the `TextField` is because you configured it correctly for the `AnchorPane` but not the `TextField`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This helped me, but I accepted Sedrick's answer because he also explained why Backspace doesn't work on KeyTyped (because it is an Action Key and action keys don't generate any unicode characters) and he also referenced the documentation, which will eventually help anyone who gets here by any source. But don't worry you were very helpful too :D .