# VK backspace not recognized, and color change for TextField

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to write key detection code to alert users to an in valid key entry. The textfield turns red if the key entry is wrong, and goes back to white when it is corrected. For some reason, Eclipse is not recognizing VK_BACK_SPACE. Is this obsolete? It's still in the Oracle Documentation for KeyEvent.
The line of code using it looks like this:

```
else if ( (event.getCharacter().compareTo("0") >= 0 
            && event.getCharacter().compareTo("9") <= 0 ) 
            || (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE))
```

Why are both getKeyCode and VK_BACK_SPACE not being recognized?

I'm also running into an issue where the color change only occurs once. I'm using a KeyHandler, and changing the CSS style for the particular TextField back and forth between red and white as input is validated. It only works the first time invalid input is entered, and is refusing to go back to white background when the input is corrected.

The code looks like this:

```
EventHandler backgroundChanger = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if ( (event.getCharacter().compareTo("a") >= 0 
                && event.getCharacter().compareTo("z") <= 0) 
                || (event.getCharacter().compareTo("A") >= 0 
                && event.getCharacter().compareTo("Z") <= 0))
        {
            backgroundChangerWrong((TextField)event.getSource());
        }

        else if ( (event.getCharacter().compareTo("0") >= 0 
                    && event.getCharacter().compareTo("9") <= 0 ) )
        {
            Background originalColor = backgroundGrab.getBackground();
            backgroundChangerRight((TextField)event.getSource(), originalColor);
        }

        else
        {
            backgroundChangerWrong((TextField)event.getSource());
        }
    }
};

TextField salaryField = new TextField();
salaryField.setPromptText("##.##");
gridPane.setConstraints(salaryField, 1, 0, 1, 1);
salaryField.getText();
salaryField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, backgroundChanger);
gridPane.getChildren().add(salaryField);
```

The background changer functions:

```
public static void backgroundChangerRight(TextField textObj, Background origBackground) {
        textObj.setBackground(origBackground);
    }

public static void backgroundChangerWrong(TextField textObj) {
        textObj.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff0000;");
        textObj.setOpacity(20);
    }
```

The CSS sheet:

```
.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff, white, white;
    -fx-border-color: grey;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-border-radius: 1;
}
```

EDIT: 
Imports:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keycode event for BACKSPACE in JavaFx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564002/keycode-event-for-backspace-in-javafx)

Comment: Structure your `if()` like the duplicate.

Comment: Also, make sure you are using `JavaFX` imports for `KeyEvent`.

Comment: Definitely have it imported, I'll edit with my full list of imports just in case

Comment: That's also not a duplicate; I should have been clearer, but it isn't an issue with KEY_TYPED vs KEY_PRESSED etc. I'm already using KEY_PRESSED, and it should be able to detect backspace using VK

Comment: [`VK_BACK_SPACE`](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.awt.event.KeyEvent&method=VK_BACK_SPACE) is `awt` not `JavaFX`. Double check your imports.

Comment: Also, don't compare they way you are. Do something like `kEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE`

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. Any idea why the background color change is only working once?

Comment: Is there any way to do multiple KeyCode conditions at once?

Comment: Doing if (event.getCode() == (KeyCode.A || KeyCode.B || etc.)) doesn't seem to work
Do they all need to be written out manually, ala 
if ((event.getCode() == KeyCode.A) || (event.getCode() == KeyCode B) etc.)

Comment: So you can't use || with KeyCode? ie. (KeyCode.A || KeyCode.B || ...) as part of an if statement

Comment: ["For key pressed and key released events, character is always CHAR_UNDEFINED."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCharacter--) Just don't do it this way at all: don't use key event listeners of any kind for this functionality. (For one, it won't work if the user copies and pastes text with the mouse.) Add a listener to the `textProperty()` and change the background if the text is invalid. Or, better still, use a [`TextFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) to prevent invalid input at all.

Comment: Ah, that explains that. Don't know how I missed that. Thank you!
When IS key pressed useful then? If you don't care at all about the input? (ie. to see when someone is typing)